# How to move an object with actionscript from with in itself?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to be able to change the x value of an object from with in its own timeline.
The object has been created with actionscript so it does not have an instance name.

So I'm just wondering if there is a command like `self` or something so I can move an object.

Eg

self.x = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with

```
this.x = 0;
```

or just

```
x = 0;
```

But if your display objects tree is deeply nested, these values will be relative to the object they've been added to. So if you need relative coordinates - just move it with *this.x* or *x*, and if you need global ones - use [localToGlobal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) method